# PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

```
public class OTPFragment extends Fragment {   
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private String mVerificationId = null;
```

initializing Firebase and instance in oncreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this.getActivity();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    initFirebaseCallback();
}
```

here got the error in PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance

```
 private void sendOtp(String phoneNumber) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+91"+mobileNumber,         // Phone number to verify
            60,               // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            getActivity(),// Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}
```

callback and everything is initialized before calling .verifyphonenumber
Got error with this code,the log is

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(java.lang.String, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit, 
   com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider$OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, 
   android.app.Activity, java.util.concurrent.Executor, boolean, java.lang.String)' on a null object 
   reference
```

callback method

```
  private void initFirebaseCallback() {
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() 
   {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                //error
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                               @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken 
token) {

            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you initialize your callbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer;

FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); itself returning a null

I added tools:node="merge" in my manifest under application tag" it works fine.

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".util.Application"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_app_icon_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:node="merge">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the changes as below

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

//onCreate ...

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

//Change your sendOtp function to..

```
private void sendOtp(String phoneNumber){
PhoneAuthOptions options =
PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
.setPhoneNumber("+91"+phoneNumber) // Phone number to verify
.setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
.setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
.setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
.build();
PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}
```