# get Instance error in Java android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on this android application and I keep getting an error when I try to use the getInstance().

```
**PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber**
whilst using the above method I get a warning saying the method is deprecated. what should I do?
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error" Please edit your question (there's a link right under it for that purpose) to include the exact error message and stack trace you get. I also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we'll probably also need to see a bit more code than what you shared so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762584/13082664

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.